Problem characterizing Lindenbaum algebras
Given a first order type $\tau$, we use $S^\tau$ to denote the set of $\tau$-sentences,
i.e. formulas with no free variables. Let $T = (\Sigma, \tau)$ a theory, with $\Sigma$ the set of axioms in the theory. Then we can define
\begin{equation*}
    \varphi \dashv \vdash_T \psi \iff T \vdash \left( \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi \right) 
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
    \dashv \vdash_T = \left\{ (\varphi, \psi) \in S^\tau : T \vdash \left( \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi \right)  \right\} 
\end{equation*}
We accept without proof that $\dashv \vdash_T$ is
an equivalence relation.
We say that a sentence $\varphi \in S^\tau$ is refutable when $(\Sigma, \tau)
\vdash \neg \varphi$. We also accept without proof that the
set of theorems and the set of refutable sentences form two distinct equivalent
classes under $\dashv \vdash $.
Let $\left[ \varphi \right] $ denote the equivalent class of $\varphi$
with respect to $\dashv \vdash_T $. Define $\textbf{s}$
as
\begin{align*}
&\left[ \varphi \right]  \textbf{ s } \left[ \psi \right] = \left[ \left( \varphi \lor  \psi \right)  \right] \\
    &\left[ \varphi \right] \textbf{ i } \left[ \psi \right] = \left[ \left( \varphi \land  \psi \right)  \right] \\ 
    &\left( \left[ \varphi \right]  \right)^c = \left[ \neg \varphi \right] 
\end{align*}
With $0^T$ as the set of refutable sentences in $T$, $1^T$ as the set of theorems
in $T$,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{B} = \left( S^\tau / \dashv \vdash_T, \textbf{s}, \textbf{i}, ~^c, 0^T, 1^T \right) 
\end{equation*}
is a Boolean algebra, known as the Lindenbaum algebra
(under theory $T$).
I find it difficult to characterize the elements the algebra. It can be proven that the order induced by this algebra is
\begin{equation*}
    \left[ \varphi \right] \leq \left[ \psi \right]  \iff T \vdash \left( \varphi \to \psi \right) 
\end{equation*}
$0^T$ is the set of refutable sentences, and anything can be deduced from a refutable sentence, so we see that indeed $0^T \leq [\varphi]$ for any $[\varphi]$, as we would expect. But what elements cover $0^T$? How many elements that cover $0^T$ are there? In the Hasse diagram, how many "levels" exist between $0^T$ and $1^T$, and what characterizes the equivalent classes in these leves?

The algebra is typically infinite, so you shouldn’t expect a Hasse diagram to be helpful.

"We also accept without proof that the set of theorems and the set of refutable sentences form two distinct equivalent classes..." They are distinct if and only if $T$ is consistent.

The elements covering $0_T$, if there are any at all, correspond to the completions (= complete consistent extensions) of $T$ which are finitely axiomatizable over $T$, that is, which have the form $T+\{\varphi\}$ for some sentence $\varphi$. Many natural $T$ admit no such extensions at all. For example, consider the case of Robinson arithmetic $\mathsf{Q}$, and apply Godel's incompleteness theorem. Indeed, by GIT the Lindenbaum algebra of $\mathsf{Q}$ is dense, while some other theories have much simpler Lindenbaum algebras; see this old answer of mine.
In general, you should not expect the Lindenbaum algebra to be especially easy to visualize.

Thanks, that was helpful!
